# "Undefined Reference" using mingw and fltk library

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, mingw32, fltk

I'm trying to compile a .cpp file to output .exe file using the following command

```
86_64-w64-mingw32-g++  helloworld.cpp -I/usr/include/eigen3 -Ifltk-1.3.7 -Lfltk-1.3.7/lib -lfltk_images -lfltk -lX11 -lXfixes -lXext -ldl  -o Decision_Master.exe
```

But I'm getting the following errors

```
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccAf2P0k.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1753): undefined reference to `Fl_Text_Display::buffer(Fl_Text_Buffer*)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccAf2P0k.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1b28): undefined reference to `Fl_Widget::label(char const*)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccAf2P0k.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1b3b): undefined reference to `Fl_Input_::value(char const*)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccAf2P0k.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1c99): undefined reference to `Fl_Input_::value(char const*)'
```

Knowing that if I ran it through g++ it works with no problems .. as in the command below

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -I/usr/include/eigen3 -Ifltk-1.3.7 -Lfltk-1.3.7/lib -lfltk -lX11 -lXfixes -lXext -ldl -lfltk_images -o hello_world
```

The whole story is running on Ubuntu 20.04, I don't know if the information below are useful as well.

```
ux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear in which environment you run g++, is it in an msys2 shell, wsl or something else. From the link flags it seems you also link xlib so it's most likely wsl or some linux/bsd distro. mingw-g++ is a port of g++ to windows, it can't use fltk binaries that are not built for windows. So if you have libfltk installed for wsl, mingw-g++ can't find it nor use it.

Comment: This is on ubuntu 20.04. I'm really still a nobe in this stuff, so I don't understand most of what you said. So any chance that this would work ?

Comment: Can you add the contents of `helloworld.cpp`?

Comment: It basically means that a library built for ubuntu can't be used for windows, and vice versa. What you're trying to accomplish is cross-compiling an fltk app from ubuntu to windows, as such, you'll have to also build fltk for windows using mingw, then link your app to that fltk build. Notice that windows also doesn't have X11, so the compiler invokation would also fail.

Comment: The order in which the libraries appear is important.  In the first case fltk_image appears before fltk.  In the second it appears after.  Can you try it in the same order as the *working* and tell us what happens.

Comment: Can you also post your file structure?  Looks like you have fltk one level below the source.  Is that correct?

Comment: Is your command referencing a 86_64-w64-mingw32 build of fltk? If not and you're trying to link with an Ubuntu library then that may be your problem...